# How do I get rid of the sucking bugs eating the leaves in my garden?

Tags: pest-control

I have a permaculture garden which is overrun by these red/black bugs which are killing plant leaves. How do I get rid of them, preferably without spraying pesticides?

Comment: Could you throw up a picture of the bugs? Does it look like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxelder_bug ?

Comment: Really need some pictures, your zone and what plants are being decimated.  There will always be 'bugs' and slugs that chew on your plants.  Normally, not at all a deal breaker!  Not enough reason to bring out the nuclear bombs, grins!  What is your definition of your permaculture garden?  Culture is constant energy input..Permanent usually means On Automatic.

Comment: A little bit of soap and water gets rid of most insects